# How to fix "list index out of range" error for a python code that returns the max increase within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've written up this code to get me the maximum increase from a smaller element to a larger one of a higher index, with the trend in between only increasing, but I hit a "list" and "tuple index out of range" error at "while seq[index + 1] > seq[index]"

so for successful examples:

```
max_increase((1,2,3,2)) == 2.0
```

and

```
max_increase([3,-1,2,1]) == 3.0
```

this is my code below:

```
def max_increase(seq):
    index = 1
    inc = 0
    diff = 0
    n = 1
    for index in range(1, len(seq)):
        if seq[index] > seq[index - 1]:
            diff = seq[index] - seq[index - 1]
            while seq[index + 1] > seq[index]:
                diff += seq[index + n] - seq[index]
                index = index + 1
            if diff > inc:
                inc = diff
            index = index + 1 
        else:
            index = index + 1
    return inc
```

Not really any minimum code but basic code is preferred as this is an introductory coding course :)

Tests that got me the error are:

```
max_increase([1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0]) == 2.0
```

and

```
btc_data = [ 6729.44, 6690.88, 6526.36, 6359.98, 6475.89, 6258.74,
             6485.10, 6396.64, 6579.00, 6313.51, 6270.20, 6195.01,
             6253.67, 6313.90, 6233.10, 6139.99, 6546.45, 6282.50,
             6718.22, 6941.20, 7030.01, 7017.61, 7414.08, 7533.92,
             7603.99, 7725.43, 8170.01, 8216.74, 8235.70, 8188.00,
             7939.00, 8174.06 ]
btc_data.reverse()
assert abs(max_increase(tuple(btc_data))-589.45) < 1e-6
```

Answer (score 0):

you put extra condition like this, looks like you have programmatic error

```
def max_increase(seq):
    index = 1
    inc = 0
    diff = 0
    n = 1
    for index in range(1, len(seq)):
        if seq[index] > seq[index - 1]:
            diff = seq[index] - seq[index - 1]
            while index != (len(seq)-1) and seq[index + 1] > seq[index]:
                diff += seq[index + n] - seq[index]
                index = index + 1
            if diff > inc:
                inc = diff
            index = index + 1 
        else:
            index = index + 1
    return inc

max_increase([1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0]) == 2.0
```

Comment: Hi Prashant. Thank you for the suggestion! Yes it did work for [1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0]. But for abs(max_increase(tuple(btc_data))-589.45) < 1e-6 the test fails. Any idea on why that is?